# Not able to invoke javascript function in html:text

Tags: javascript, struts-1

I am using struts 1.
I have a textbox like this

```
<html:text name="test" property="testProperty" size="10" onBlur="someJavascriptFunc()"  />
```

Its throwing an error while compiling

```
Attribute onBlur invalid for tag text according to TLD
```

How can I invole this javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your JavaScript Code

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
x.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "javascript:return someJavascriptFunc()");
```

Comment: it needs to be called on page load?

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta: you can call it in `window.onload = function(e){ 
   var x = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
x.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "javascript:return someJavascriptFunc()");
}` inside your script tags and also define `someJavascriptFunc()` in the script tags

Comment: Thanks for your help.It worked when I changed from `onBlur` to `onblur`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [documentation](http://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/text.html) and found that its actually `onblur`.

It worked when I changed function name `onBlur` to `onblur`.